# How is margins calculated for textView when it is set upside down?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I do this:

```
        question1.setRotation(180);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for_question1_x = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        for_question1_x.setMargins(935, 465, 0, 0);
        question1.setLayoutParams(for_question1_x);
        question1.requestLayout();
```

However, my question textView appears at somewhat diffrent place. I dont know why.
It is upside down, but appears much closer to the left angle.

So I wonder, does anyone know if the origin point (0,0) is not upperleft corner for Views upside down?

Comment: This might help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: ok, i managed to bandaid the bug, not fix it